Pandas Multiple Columns explode
I have a dataframe with one row like below:



col1
col2
col3




[a,b,c]
[i,ii,iii]
[1,2,3]



Now I need to transfer it into -



col1
col2
col3




a
i
1


b
ii
2


c
iii
3



I have tried to use explode. But select clause allowed only one explode function which is very logical.
Can anyone help me with this?

There's an existing question about this for Pandas. But I'm not sure what you mean by "select clause" and I see comments about Pyspark. If the linked question isn't helpful, make a [mre] and LMK. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

I was looking for a solution with pyspark actually. But solved it with pandas. Someone asked me to change the question. So did it. I am still looking for the solution with pyspark.

Another possible solution (assuming that, by row, all lists have the same length):
df.explode(df.columns.to_list())

Output:
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    i    1
0    b   ii    2
0    c  iii    3


You can do this:
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.columns, df.to_numpy().flatten())))

I think it is more efficient than apply/explode.

So the solution is:
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)

